# Hide Django settings value (for Celery) on error page

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-settings, traceback

We're using Celery in our Django project and put a `CELERY_RESULT_DBURI` value (which carries the password to our database) into our `settings.py` file. Obviously, I don't feel very safe having the password in plaintext in every traceback.

I know about [Filtering Error Reports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-reports) but the only solution I can think of right now is to rewrite the `SafeExceptionReporterFilter` class by copying the `get_traceback_frame_variables()` method and monkey-patching `CELERY_RESULT_DBURI` into it somehow. Does anyone of you know a better solution? How did you work around the problem of exposing the database password?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I can't think of a case when a password setting would appear in a traceback. Tracebacks include only function calls, and so a variable assignment would never show up. I know variables will be displayed if DEBUG is set to True, but that should not be a problem on production sites.

Comment: You're right. I didn't mean the variables in the traceback but the settings which are additionally printed after a traceback on Django's error pages and in error mails. You're also right that this does not apply if `DEBUG = False` but I don't want to have to rely on that. It would simply be inexcusable if the password was to be printed to the end user if some developer accidentally left `DEBUG = True` and an error was triggered.

One could add `CELERY_RESULT_DBURI` to django.views.debug.HIDDEN_SETTINGS but I have no idea on how to do that properly (i.e. without modifying Django's source).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I wanted to post an answer since I came across this question when I was researching a similar problem. OP was on the right track about about filtering error reports. I hope this helps someone!

```
import re
from django.views.debug import SafeExceptionReporterFilter

# These are the default patterns Django will match as of 4.2
HIDDEN_DEFAULT = 'API|TOKEN|KEY|SECRET|PASS|SIGNATURE|HTTP_COOKIE|'
EXTRA = 'CELERY|SOME_OTHER_KEY'

class CustomExceptionReporterFilter(SafeExceptionReporterFilter):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_settings = re.compile(
            pattern=f'{HIDDEN_DEFAULT}{EXTRA}',
            flags=re.IGNORECASE
        )
```

Then add this to your settings.py file:

```
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = "path.to.module.CustomExceptionReporterFilter"
```

Here is some additional information on custom error reporting in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/error-reporting/#custom-error-reports